# I have error that I don't know how to fix for my AP computer science class

Tags: drjava

So I need some help with my APCS class. We have to make a code that with a specific runner class, would tell you if the discriminate on the quadratic formula is positive or without real solutions. This is my code so far, but I keep getting the error
"Error: Syntax error on token ",", invalid AssignmentOperator"
This is my code

```
import static java.lang.Math.*;
public class Quadratic
{
 private double a,b,c;
  public Quadratic(double aa, double bb, double cc)
  {
    a=aa;
    b=bb;
    c=cc;
}
public boolean hasSolutions ()
  double calcDisc = Math.pow((b,2)-(4*a*c));
  if (CalcDisc < 0)
  {
    return false;
  }
  else
  {
    return true;
  }
}
}
```

The line that says "double calcDisc = Math.pow((b,2)-(4*a*c));

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to do b^2 - 4*a*c?

That would be Math.pow(b,2) - (4*a*c)

Answer (score 0):

Math.pow(x,y) takes two parameters.
But you are trying to pass in `(b,2)-(4*a*c)` as the argument.
Since you have `(b,2)` in the expression, it doesn't make sense, thus the error message you are seeing.

I'm guessing what you actually want is:
`double calcDisc = Math.pow(b,2)-(4*a*c)`

Which subtracts (4*a*c) from b^2

Comment: I have thisdouble calcDisc = Math.pow(b,2)-(4*a*c);

Comment: I have this                                                                                           double calcDisc = Math.pow(b,2)-(4*a*c);                                                             but I'm having the same error. @MysticXG

Comment: @FaridNat If your code in original post is identical, you're also missing the opening bracket for the hasSolution function.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have one level too many parenthesis.

```
  double calcDisc = Math.pow((b,2)-(4*a*c));
```

Should be:

```
  double calcDisc = Math.pow(b,2)-(4*a*c);
```